# Frobenius/Schur orthogonality relations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

I was going through following exercise from Isaacs' character theory. I solved the exercise, but my question here is about a note after it. The exercise is stated below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**Q.1** I tried to give proof of *Note*; I thought the orthogonality of characters can be proved, but how about orthogonality involving conjugacy classes?

To be precise, the author states following orthogonality relations, among which I couldn't prove (2.18) from (2.20), the above Schur relations. Can we obtain it?

> [image]
>   [image]

**Q.2** Among (2.20), (2.14) and (2.18), which relations are exactly the Frobenius' orthogonality relations and which are Schur's orthogonality relations? Frobenius states in terms of characters perhaps, does Schur also give orthogonality in terms of characters? or matrix representations?

Comment: I don't know whether this was the intended proof, but (2,18) can be derived from (2.14) from the fact that $AB = I_n \Rightarrow BA=I_n$ for $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Derek: yes, this is the way almost all books describe. I raised above question because Isaacs says *They can be used to give another proof of* ***the*** *orthogonality relations*, and I thought, he may want to say that  **both** the orthogonality relations can be derived from 2.20.

Comment: It is possible that Isaacs is regarding (2.14) and (2.18) as being equivalent since they can be derived from each other using basic linear algebra, in which case he would regard deriving one as being equivalent to derivi ng the other, but I don't really know!